# Cant view table of SQL server 2005 in Netbeans 7.1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, netbeans, jdbc, netbeans-7

I'm currently using netbeans. At runtime view, I am able to connect to my sqlserver 2005 database. However, the list of tables are not shown. When I try to execute the command I could successfully query the database, tables and fields. I'm just wondering why the tables are not shown in the runtime view's table folder.

I am using JDBC drive : 4.0 
Netbeans : 7.1

Config Entires

Host : 172.16.16.18 
port :1433
DataBase: Alpha
Instance Name :
username : username
password:password

Already tried by changing various schema .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone come for solution of the same problem . Use this driver
http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/6/A/D6A241AC-433E-4CD2-A1CE-50177E8428F0/1033/sqljdbc_3.0.1301.101_enu.tar.gz

THere is some bug in there new drive ...

I HATE Microsoft ........